# What Is Wrong With This Javascript Object Code?

Tags: javascript

```
var Detector = function() {
    var baseFonts = ['monospace', 'sans-serif', 'serif'];
    var testString = "mmmmmmmmmmlli";

    var testSize = '72px';
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    // create a SPAN in the document to get the width of the text we use to test
    var s = document.createElement("span");
    s.style.fontSize = testSize;
    s.innerHTML = testString;
    var defaultWidth = {};
    var defaultHeight = {};
    for (var index in baseFonts) {
        //get the default width for the three base fonts
        s.style.fontFamily = baseFonts[index];
        h.appendChild(s);
        defaultWidth[baseFonts[index]] = s.offsetWidth; //width for the default font
        defaultHeight[baseFonts[index]] = s.offsetHeight; //height for the defualt font
        h.removeChild(s);
    }

    function detect(font) {
        var detected = false;
        for (var index in baseFonts) {
            s.style.fontFamily = font + ',' + baseFonts[index]; // name of the font along with the base font for fallback.
            h.appendChild(s);
            var matched = (s.offsetWidth != defaultWidth[baseFonts[index]] || s.offsetHeight != defaultHeight[baseFonts[index]]);
            h.removeChild(s);
            detected = detected || matched;
        }
        return detected;
    }

    this.detect = detect;
};
var d = new Detector();
alert(d.detect("Times"));
```

//downloaded from http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/

This checks for `fonts` installed on the system by indirect method of implications. Somehow it was working perfectly on my webpage at first. I added in some more coding and now it has stopped working. I have removed all that coding and reverted the coding to that which was working initially, but it is still not working. I have tried copy-pasting it to some other pages and it is still not working there either. But when I post all this code as text and run an `eval()` on it, suddenly it starts working. I'm going mad. Can somebody please resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier just to use a font fallback within your CSS? Seems like an awful lot of JavaScript to do something that CSS can do in one line. That is assuming it's for a practical purpose.

Comment: And how can I check for installed fonts on the system using CSS? Please elaborate.

Comment: You don't need to check. doing `font-family: 'mycustomfont', Arial;` Will solve your issue, because if 'mycustomfont' isn't installed on the users computer, arial will be used. A good workaround would be to use webfonts.

Comment: Never mind. My problem is resolved now. The details are posted below.

Answer (score 0):

OK I stumbled upon the real issue randomly. It keeps happening to me all the time when I use DOM references in my javascript. It's pretty little thing and is easily overlooked but thats what it makes all the more annoying and hard to catch.

**I was using this code in the head section, before the body tag. Cutting it from there and pasting it after the body code resolved the issue.** The reason appears to be that since this code tries to create a span object inside the body section, using this code before the body tag will end up in a logical error because by that time, the body object doesn't exist. Relocating the code beyond the body section rectified the issue and the code is running smoothly now. Thanks to all who contributed.